# Why is there extra padding happening in my div?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've coded my website for all browsers but of course IE has issues. Specifically only IE 7. I'm hoping to find a resolution to why it's behaving the way it is with two issues and what I can add so IE will display it properly.

My submit buttons are aligning to the bottom of their containing divs.

[image]

CSS for the SUBMIT button for the SEARCH field

```
#searchform { /*container widget */ position: relative; left: 15px; width: 97%; height: 30px; background-color: #f3f3f3; border: 2px solid #742222;}

#searchform label { display: none; }

#searchform input#s { width: 75%; height: 20px;}

input[type=text],input#s { margin: 0 10px 0 0; width: 60%; }

#searchsubmit{ position: relative; float: right; width: 30px; height: 30px; text-indent: -999px; background: url(http://averylawoffice.ca/img/SEARCH-submit.jpg) center; border: 0px;}
```

This CSS works in all browsers but IE version 7. Is there a way to make it top align without having to position absolute?

Comment: Can't you post the URL to that page? Those kinds of issues are best investigated live with the browser's dev tools.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: It's almost certainly http://www.averylawoffice.ca/averywordpress/. I remembered that the URL has been posted in a prior question.

Comment: What if you add a position relative rule to the div containing that input element, remove the float right rule on the input element, and add a position absolute, top 0px, and right 0px to the input element.

Comment: If everything works except IE7, what about redirecting IE7 users to the Chrome or Firefox download page?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, thrirtydot figured it out, I had an empty <header> div that was causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to move the SUBMIT button up (to the correct position) by left-floating the text-box.

```
.subscription_email {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

Same goes for the search text-box:

```
#s {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

By making those changes, the resulting presentation will be exactly the same as in Firefox.

Comment: *sigh* It's always something simple with IE. One day I'll get the hang of it. Thanks! Could you possibly help me out with the last issue I'm having with IE? It seems it's pushing the logo, links and banner down and I'm not sure why. My padding and margin is set to 0 but it's doing something with it...Do you know why it's doing that?

Comment: @Amber: The gap is coming from `<header></header>`.

Comment: Wow. Duh. Rookie mistake. Thanks thirtydot.

Comment: @Amber Yup! It's the HEADER element which is being inserted in front of the `#main-navigation` element. It's empty, so just hide it: `header { ... display:none; }`

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm so happy to be done this site! That was the last 2 issues I had with it!! Thanks!